# Is it possible to serialize an APEX sub-class outside of a managed package from within a MP dynamically?

Tags: managed-package, json, serialization

I have an apex class within the package calling `JSON.serializePretty()` of an instance of a apex sub-class outside that package. I encounter this following error `Type cannot be serialized` so I dug a bit further from other questions but the solutions are for packages doing serialization between each other.
Providing an example in hopes to explain what I want to achieve

```
global class OutsideClassA {
  global class SubClass {
    global Map<String, OutsideClassB.SubClass> data = new Map<String, OutsideClassB.SubClass>
    global SubClass() {
      // ...
    } 
  }
}
```

```
public class InsidePackageClass {
  public static String getSerialized() {
    return JSON.serializePretty( Type.forName('OutsideClassA.SubClass').newInstance() );
  }
}
```

Comment: Nested classes defined in the subscriber org and that are defined as global in a global outer class can definitely be serialized and deserialized with JSON in managed package code. In my experience I see this error is typically when the class in question includes a property/attribute where the type is a Salesforce API type that does not support JSON serialization/deserialization - e.g. `SObjectType` or `DescribeFieldResult`. Do you have this scenario? If you do, try setting that property/attribute as `transient` so it is ignored in serialize/deserialize.

Comment: @PhilW That's my immediate thought, too. IF you add that as an answer, I'd upvote it.

Comment: @sfdcfox, done with a little more explanation around transient too.

Comment: Is OutsideClassB.SubClass also global? If not, that could be problematic.

Answer (score 6):

Nested classes defined in the subscriber org and that are defined as global in a global outer class can definitely be serialized and deserialized with JSON in managed package code.

In my experience I see this error typically when the class in question includes a property/attribute where the type is a Salesforce API type that does not support JSON serialization/deserialization - e.g. `SObjectType` or `DescribeFieldResult` etc. (Another problem case is if you try to have a nested class implement `Database.Batchable`.)

If you have such an unserializable property scenario, setting that property/attribute as `transient`, so it is ignored in serialize/deserialize, is a solution as long as you write the code to handle the case where this property/attribute is null.

Comment: I am unable to serialize the bare sub-class, even with just an empty constructor I get the same error. As you already noticed `OutsideClassA.SubClass` isn't a Salesforce API type so it should work.

Comment: I am talking about the properties/attributes of the nested class.

Comment: When you say "bare (nested) class" do you mean one with no properties/attributes?

Comment: Yes. I mean just a plain (nested) class with an empty constructor even and that does not work.

Comment: OK, that is rather unexpected. Is the constructor declared global as well?

Comment: Have you considered using Type.forName with two parameters, setting the namespace to ""? If your code needs to handle instantiating classes from various namespaces or the no-namespace (subscriber org), separating namespace from class name makes sense.

Comment: The constructor is also global. In the API documentation they suggest to use the variant without the explicit namespace for the current case. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_type.htm#apex_System_Type_forName_2

Comment: I understand, but have you tried the other form? Indeed, I read that documentation as recommending the variant with namespace set null/empty: "Use this method instead of forName(fullyQualifiedName) if it will be called from a managed package installed in an organization with no defined namespace. To get the name of a local type, set the namespace argument to an empty string or null. For example, Type t = Type.forName('', 'ClassName');"

Comment: Yes I tried your suggestion and it did not work unfortunately.

Comment: This is very odd. I am sure we have successfully achieved this before as outlined.

Comment: We have reduced the classes both top-level and sub-class to only constructors and one bare global string members initialized with "123". constructors are global, too. we verified: in execute anonymous all works fine. But doing the very same in the package fails. After that, we tried to use an interface instead. moving the serialization to a method. we put the interface into the package. this doesn't work either, because the cast to the interface generates an runtime error. now we are gonna abusing a VF page to render the JSON and suck it in with PageReference.getContent(). Which is most awful.

Comment: Very strange. I wonder if something changed, or I have misremembered the scenario where we did this...

Comment: We definitely use the two parameters overload of forType.

Comment: we've tried both: one and two params overload. Neither works. There must be something on the meta-info of the classes, or the API-Version or something wired. Hard to rapidly try different ideas because of the upload-install-loop. API is v52.0

Comment: All I can say is good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The one-parameter version of `Type.forName` assumes that the format is "Namespace.ClassName.SubClass", which might be the problem. Since you provide `OuterClassA.SubClass` to this method, it assumes you want `SubClass` from namespace `OuterClassA`.

Try using the two-parameter version with an empty string or null as the first parameter:

```
public static String getSerialized() {
  return JSON.serializePretty( Type.forName(null, 'OutsideClassA.SubClass').newInstance() );
}
```

Failing that, have the external class require serialization. I would consider using Callable for this:

```
public static String getSerialized() {
  Callable x = (Callable)(Type.forName('','OutsideClassA.SubClass').newInstance());
  return (String)x.call(null, null);
}
```

Where the class that would do the work would be:

```
global class OutsideClassA {
  global class SubClass implements Callable {
    global Object call(String action, Map<String, Object> args) {
      return JSON.serializePretty(this);
    }
  }
}
```

Or, if you don't want to use Callable, you can also make your own global interface:

```
global interface MpSerializeRequest {
  String serialize();
}
```

Which OutsideClassA.SubClass can then implement:

```
global class OutsideClassA {
  global class SubClass implements MP.MpSerializeRequest {
    global String serialize() {
      return JSON.serializePretty(this);
    }
  }
}
```

I apologize for being kind of vague with this, as you stated, the build/install/test loop takes a lot of time that I can't invest at the exact moment, but I believe these solutions should be tested in the order I've provided. My educated guess would be that the first solution should work.